# cannot create empty SharePoint 2013 project in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013

I have installed Visual Studio 2012 Premium, SharePoint 2013 Server and Microsoft Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2012. I made changes as following post in host file. I loged on as Administrator and is dbowner of content database. but still getting error:

Cannot connect to the targeted site. This error can occur if the specified site is not hosted on the local system. SharePoint solutions work only with locally-installed versions of SharePoint Foundation or SharePoint Server. Remote development is supported only for apps for SharePoint 2013

This the post:http://www.mavention.nl/blog/cannot-connect-to-the-targeted-site-error-visual-studio-2012-rc-sharepoint-developer-tools-host-headers

Comment: This problem is solved. The web application (Root level site collection) must run on port 80. my mistake I had created the web application on another port 24532.